# Only last cell showing the graph in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-plot

I am adding the graph on my `UITableViewCell` using the core plot library .Currently in it working but adding the graph only on the last cell all above cell are remains blank . Following is my code for the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray *objects=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    CustomCell *cell=(CustomCell *)[objects objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.graphView.hostedGraph=graph;
    [graph reloadData];
     return cell;

}
```

I have checked by breakpoint graph is not null.  Can any one help me in where am I missing the trick ?

Comment: It may be a problem to add the same instance to multiple graphviews? Have you tried allocating a new "graph" and adding it to each cell instead of reusing the same instance? That will help you isolating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add

```
return cell;
```

at the end of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Hey do like this...

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    static NSString *cellId=@"cellID";
    CustomCell  *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    NSArray *objects=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
         cell=[objects objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.graphView.hostedGraph=graph;
        [graph reloadData];
         return cell;
    }
```